# How traverse model data from Controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, controller

I am using codeigniter. From a model i have fetched some data in the controller using the following codes:

```
$data['english'] = $this->question_model->getRandomQuestions('english', 2);
```

So I know to access the data from view i would use the following code..

```
foreach($english as $eng){
  echo $eng['columnName'];
}
```

But I want to travase the data in the controller doing some of my calculation. But how can I do that. I used the save above code in controller but it is then showing error.
The error message is as below :

```
Undefined variable: english
```

How can used those obtained data in controller using foreach loop. Any help would be appreciated...
thanx

Answer (score 0):

Since the response is added in $data['english'] in your controller, then you would do:

```
foreach( $data['english'] as $i => $eng ) {
   $data['english'][$i]['columnName'] = 'change with whatever';
}
```